# Set by Default Sorted or Not?

Tags: java

**UPDATED**:

```
    Set s = new HashSet();
    s.add(1);
    s.add(5);
    s.add(4);
    s.add(9);
    s.add(7);
    s.add(8);        
    s.add("b");
    s.add("a");
    s.add("B");
    s.add("A");
    s.add("s");
    s.add("x");        
    s.add("d");        
    System.out.println(s);
    s.remove("b");
    s.remove("d");
    System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
[1, d, 4, b, 5, A, B, 7, a, 8, 9, s, x]
[1, 4, 5, A, B, 7, a, 8, 9, s, x]
[1, 4, 5, A, B, 7, a, 8, 9, s, x]
```

Need some information that Set default sort Integer value when we add but if i Add String to Set it would not sort by default.

**Update:**
and Also Caps letter would always Sorted after runs many times.

java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

please give me some idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashSet` does not guaranteed that its contents will be sorted in any way. There is a special interface for sets that do provide such a guarantee: it's called [`SortedSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html):

> A `Set` that further provides a total ordering on its elements. The
>   elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a `Comparator`
>   typically provided at sorted set creation time. The set's iterator
>   will traverse the set in ascending element order. Several additional
>   operations are provided to take advantage of the ordering. (This
>   interface is the set analogue of `SortedMap`.)

In Java 6, there are two classes that implement this interface: [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) and [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Answer (score 3):

No, `HashSet` is *not* sorted - or at least, not reliably. You may *happen* to get ordering in some situations, but you *must not rely on it*. For example, it's *possible* that it will always return the entries sorted by "hash code modulo some prime" - but it's not guaranteed, and it's almost certainly not useful anyway.

If you need a sorted set implementation, look at [`TreeSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Comment: Indeed, if your hash table gets resized, the order changes completely. :-)

Comment: thanks, @ChrisJester-Young: as i resized by removing "b", "d" but the out put would be same

Comment: @Ravi: That wasn't what I meant by resizing the hash table. Try inserting enough items to go above your hashmap's load factor and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle documentation we can find the HashSet class implements the set interface
and internally backed by Hash Table.It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.
But My code Which is given bellow finds it sorted even after running number of time.

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rand = new Random(47);           
        SortedSet<Integer> intset = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> intsetUnsorted = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
            intset.add(rand.nextInt(30));
        }
        intsetUnsorted.add(500);
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
            intsetUnsorted.add(rand.nextInt(30));
        }
        String version = System.getProperty("java.version");
        System.out.println("JDK version-"+version);     
        System.out.println("TreeSet o/p");
        System.out.println(intset);
        System.out.println("Hash Set o/p");
        System.out.println(intsetUnsorted);

    }
```

O/P

```
JDK version-1.6.0
TreeSet o/p
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
Hash Set o/p
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 16, 19, 18, 21, 20, 23, 22, 25, 24, 27, 26, 29, 28, 500]
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you check the [Set interface javaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). In the **All Known Implementing Classes** section you have the provided implementations and if you check HashSet the first sentence answers your question.

Btw. checking javaDoc is always a good place to start ;-)

Comment: the java doc said : "..It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null element...", I think that( correct me if I'm wrong) it talks about order of insertion not sort order

Comment: It talks about iterating over the elements. You iterate over them when you print them out for example. Not sure what you mean by "sort order".